# How to merge / simplify both same query

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, foreach

I have two same query

Query 1 :

```
$request1 = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * from table1, table2 where table1.FK_license = table2.license and date = (select max(date) from table1 where user = :user)');
$request1-> execute(array(
    ':user' => $id
));
```

Query 2 :

```
$request2 = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * from table1, table2 where table1.FK_license = table2.license and date = (select max(date) from table1 where user = :user)');
$request2-> execute(array(
    ':user' => $id
));

$test = $request2->fetch();
```

But I need the first query to make a loop like this :

```
    <?php foreach ($request1 as $value) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $value['li']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['cu']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['qt']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['pk']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

And the second request only to retrieve data common to a certain line

```
$test['data_for_group_by']
```

How I can do for only use one query for do the same ? Because when I fetch the first request I can't do foreach after

Thank you

**EDIT : Final code looks like**

```
//This request allows me to create the loop to list all my articles
$request1 = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * from table1, table2 where table1.FK_license = table2.license and date = (select max(date) from table1 where user = :user)');
$request1-> execute(array(
    ':user' => $id
));


//With this query I retrieve a serial number (common to all articles) => $test['data_for_group_by']
$request2 = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * from table1, table2 where table1.FK_license = table2.license and date = (select max(date) from table1 where user = :user)');
$request2-> execute(array(
    ':user' => $id
));
$test = $request2->fetch();


//Here I count the number of article that I have
$license = $bdd->prepare('SELECT count(id) from table1 where number = :number');
$license ->execute(array(
    ":number" => $test['data_for_group_by']
    ));
$sum1 = $license->fetchColumn();


//And I recover the total weight of the articles (knowing that this details of weight this finds on another table)
$sum = $bdd->prepare('SELECT ROUND(SUM(pk), 2) from table1, table2 where table1.FK_license = table2.license and number = :number');
$sum ->execute(array(
    ":number" => $test['data_for_group_by']
    ));
$sum2 = $sum->fetchColumn();


?>

<p class="text-center">Quantity : <?php echo $sum1;?> - Weight : <?php echo $sum2;?> kg</p>

=== Foreach Loop ===
```

Comment: you just have to join both table using mysql joins

Comment: I don't need to joins it's the same but if I fetch the first I can't do foreach

Comment: you have to user foreach loop between like::  $request2 = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * from table1, table2 where table1.FK_license = table2.license and date = (select max(date) from table1 where user = :user)');
$request2-> execute(array(
    ':user' => $id
));
 ======= "foreach loop"========
$test = $request2->fetch(); ::::::::so that you can get value using for each loop before it fetch

Comment: Thank you but But I think I did not give enough details, I edited the post

Comment: The 2 queries are exactly the same and I cannot figure out what you mean by `only to retrieve data common to a certain line `. Pls provide sample data and expected output on the sample data, so we know what you are after.

Comment: @Shadow In fact, I edited the post, thank you for your help

Comment: Still the first 2 queries are the same and still cannot figure out what you want to do with the other 2 queries because I cannot see what they return at the moment. Providing the sample data and expected output would help us greatly to understand your problem.

Comment: @Shadow  I can add the weight in table1 to avoid creating a join in the last query

Comment: Is it truly such a big ask to provide a couple of records from the 2 tables and how the final results should look like on those records?

Comment: you have to user foreach loop before $test = $request2->fetch(); i mean you can user between them if you want some data using foreach loop because if you do that then fetch does not affect foreach loop..

Comment: @Jenish I can use foreach before request2 because I need data of request2 before my loop (I have edited my post so look like : `<p class="text-center">Quantity : <?php echo $sum1;?> - Weight : <?php echo $sum2;?> kg</p>

=== Foreach Loop ===`